# Tomcat Install MongoDB Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat

Is there a specific way to add a library to tomcat without embedding it inside every webapp? Under the directory

```
/usr/share/tomcat7/lib
```

I have put the main mongodb driver which allows me to deploy war files without no class def found exceptions but when trying to connect to a servlet this error occurs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/mongodb/MongoClient;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2509)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5209)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoClient
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1712)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1557)
    ... 41 more
```

Which appears on the line with MongoClient:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/login"}, loadOnStartup = 1)

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();

    public LoginServlet() {
        super();
    }

}
```

Is this not the correct way to install a cross webapp library?